# What is the difference between launch/join and async/await in Kotlin coroutines

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

In the `kotlinx.coroutines` library you can start new coroutine using either `launch` (with `join`) or `async` (with `await`). What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 388, accepted):

- [`launch`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) is used to **fire and forget coroutine**. It is like starting a new thread. If the code inside the `launch` terminates with exception, then it is treated like *uncaught* exception in a thread -- usually printed to stderr in backend JVM applications and crashes Android applications. [`join`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/join.html) is used to wait for completion of the launched coroutine and it does not propagate its exception. However, a crashed *child* coroutine cancels its parent with the corresponding exception, too.
- [`async`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html) is used to **start a coroutine that computes some result**. The result is represented by an instance of [`Deferred`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/index.html) and you **must** use [`await`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/await.html) on it. An uncaught exception inside the `async` code is stored inside the resulting `Deferred` and is not delivered anywhere else, it will get silently dropped unless processed. **You MUST NOT forget about the coroutine you’ve started with async**.

Comment: is Async the right coroutine builder for network calls in Android?

Comment: The right coroutine builder depends on what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Can you elaborate on "You MUST NOT forget about the coroutine you've started with async"? Are there gotchas that one wouldn't expect for example?

Comment: "An uncaught exception inside the async code is stored inside the resulting Deferred and is not delivered anywhere else, it will get silently dropped unless processed."

Comment: What exactly determines "usually printed to stderr in backend JVM applications and crashes Android applications"? `Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`?

Comment: This behavior can be overriden in various ways.

Comment: So if I'd like to propagate an exception that may occur in some "fire and forget" code, should I use `async<Unit>` and write some boilerplate code that awaits its completion and checks if some exception was thrown?

Comment: You'd propagate exceptions by launching your "fire and forget" code with a parent coroutine or by installing your own `CoroutineExceptionHandler` in the context.

Comment: I believe I can use async{} and forget it (not await for result). In such case it shall finish computation and be garbage-collected. Or not? Why you write "you must...", what happens if I don't (call await)?

Comment: If you forget the result of async than it will finish and will be garbage collected. However, if it crashes due to some bug in your code, you'll never learn about that. That is why.

Comment: if I run `launch` in a coroutine in `Dispatcher.IO` on Android, I wonder if it will swallow the exception or crash the Android app as you say...

Comment: Exception handling is unrelated to dispatcher that you use. You can learn more in the official docs on exception handling in coroutines: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html

Comment: I still wouldn't say that "you *must* use `await`" on `async`, but rather that you *should* (because of the reasons @RomanElizarov said).

Comment: Async can deliver a thrown Exception to the parent scope. Otherwise, how can one explain this? https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2404#issuecomment-732298335

Comment: This response does not tell the whole story (or I do not understand something correctly). In any case, here is a post about some weird behaviour of async: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70890920/how-does-exception-propagation-works-on-coroutinescope-async

Comment: Again - is Async the right coroutine builder for network calls in Android?

I believe, you should always prefer using `launch {}` when you're calling a `suspend fun` which makes some network request behind.

And you only need to use `async {}`, when you make 2+ network requests with the same logic block (coroutine braces { }) and need to combine their results. The only reason, I believe.

When you make just one single network request - I believe, one could just use `launch {}` and then set values to all LiveData/StateFlow right after the suspend invocation, within the same coroutine { }.

Comment: @RomanElizarov I think the description of exception handling is out-of-date now? Is it possible to an update as this still ranks highly when you search for coroutine exception handling. Or tell me I'm wrong too :-) ?

Comment: I tried this:
     GlobalScope.launch {
            
            throw java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException()

        }

But my app is not crashing, as per answer it should. What might be the cause?

Comment: It looks like this note about `async` not reporting exceptions is outdated. I think this response should be edited.

Answer (score 141):

I find [this guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md) to be useful. I will quote the essential parts.

**Coroutines**

> Essentially, coroutines are light-weight threads.

So you can think of a coroutine as something that manages thread in a very efficient way.

**launch**

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch { // launch new coroutine in background and continue
        delay(1000L) // non-blocking delay for 1 second (default time unit is ms)
        println("World!") // print after delay
    }
    println("Hello,") // main thread continues while coroutine is delayed
    Thread.sleep(2000L) // block main thread for 2 seconds to keep JVM alive
}
```

So `launch` starts a coroutine, does something, and returns a token immediately as `Job`. You can call `join` on this `Job` to block until this `launch` coroutine completes.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val job = launch { // launch new coroutine and keep a reference to its Job
        delay(1000L)
        println("World!")
    }
    println("Hello,")
    job.join() // wait until child coroutine completes
}
```

**async**

> Conceptually, `async` is just like `launch`. It starts a separate coroutine which is a light-weight thread that works concurrently with all the other coroutines. The difference is that launch returns a `Job` and does not carry any resulting value, while async returns a `Deferred` -- a light-weight non-blocking future that represents a promise to provide a result later.

So `async` starts a background thread, does something, and returns a token immediately as `Deferred`.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        val one = async { doSomethingUsefulOne() }
        val two = async { doSomethingUsefulTwo() }
        println("The answer is ${one.await() + two.await()}")
    }
    println("Completed in $time ms")
}
```

> You can use `.await()` on a deferred value to get its eventual result, but `Deferred` is also a `Job`, so you can cancel it if needed.

So `Deferred` is actually a `Job`. [Read this](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/) for more details.

```kotlin
interface Deferred<out T> : Job (source)
```

**async is eager by default**

> There is a laziness option to async using an optional start parameter with a value of `CoroutineStart.LAZY`. It starts coroutine only when its result is needed by some `await` or if a start function is invoked.

Comment: In the code block example for launch (used within runBlocking), I don't think you'd need "job.join()" since the runBlocking coroutine will wait for its children to complete. You'd only need this if you were creating a coroutine using a top-level scope, such as GlobalScope.

Comment: @Avilio it doesn't hurt, although sure, it doesn't make sense to call `join()` in this very example. Another thing: the `launch` example plainly won't compile (`launch` requires CoroutineScope).

Answer (score 18):

1. both coroutine builders namely launch and async are basically lambdas with receiver of type CoroutineScope which means their inner block is compiled as a suspend function, hence they both run in an asynchronous mode AND they both will execute their block sequentially.
2. The difference between launch and  async is that they enable two different possibilities. The launch builder returns a Job however the async function will return a Deferred object. You can use launch to execute a block that you don't expect any returned value from it i.e writing to a database or saving a file or processing something basically just called for its side effect. On the other hand async which return a Deferred as I stated previously returns a useful value from the execution of its block, an object that wraps your data, so you can use it for mainly its result but possibly for its side effect as well. N.B: you can strip the deferred and get its value using the function await, which will block the execution of your statements until a value is returned or an exceptions is thrown! You could achieve the same thing with launch by using the function join()
3. both coroutine builder (launch and async) are cancelable.
4. anything more?: yep with launch if an exception is thrown within its block, the coroutine is automatically canceled and the exceptions is delivered. On the other hand, if that happens with async the exception is not propagated further and should be caught/handled within the returned Deferred object.
5. more on coroutines https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines/coroutines-basic-jvm.html
   https://www.codementor.io/blog/kotlin-coroutines-6n53p8cbn1

Comment: Thanks for this comment. It collected all points of the thread.
I'd add that not all launches are canceled e.g. Atomic cannot be canceled ever.

Answer (score 17):

`launch` and `async` are used to start new coroutines. But, they execute them in different manner.

I would like to show very basic example which will help you understand difference very easily

> 1. **launch**

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnCount.setOnClickListener {
            pgBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                val currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
                val retVal1 = downloadTask1()
                val retVal2 = downloadTask2()
                val retVal3 = downloadTask3()
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "All tasks downloaded! ${retVal1}, ${retVal2}, ${retVal3} in ${(System.currentTimeMillis() - currentMillis)/1000} seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                pgBar.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }

    // Task 1 will take 5 seconds to complete download
    private suspend fun downloadTask1() : String {
        kotlinx.coroutines.delay(5000);
        return "Complete";
    }

    // Task 1 will take 8 seconds to complete download    
    private suspend fun downloadTask2() : Int {
        kotlinx.coroutines.delay(8000);
        return 100;
    }

    // Task 1 will take 5 seconds to complete download
    private suspend fun downloadTask3() : Float {
        kotlinx.coroutines.delay(5000);
        return 4.0f;
    }
}
```

In this example, my code is downloading 3 data on click of `btnCount` button and showing `pgBar` progress bar until all download gets completed. There are 3 `suspend` functions `downloadTask1()`, `downloadTask2()` and `downloadTask3()` which downloads data. To simulate it, I've used `delay()` in these functions. These functions waits for `5 seconds`, `8 seconds` and `5 seconds` respectively.

As we've used `launch` for starting these suspend functions, `launch` will execute them **sequentially (one-by-one)**. This means that, `downloadTask2()` would start after `downloadTask1()` gets completed and `downloadTask3()` would start only after `downloadTask2()` gets completed.

As in output screenshot `Toast`, total execution time to complete all 3 downloads would lead to **5 seconds + 8 seconds + 5 seconds = 18 seconds** with `launch`

[image: Launch Example]

> 2. **async**

As we saw that `launch` makes execution `sequentially` for all 3 tasks. The time to complete all tasks was `18 seconds`.

If those tasks are independent and if they do not need other task's computation result, we can make them run `concurrently`. They would start at same time and run concurrently in background. This can be done with `async`.

`async` returns an instance of `Deffered<T>` type, where `T` is type of data our suspend function returns. For example,

- `downloadTask1()` would return `Deferred<String>` as String is return type of function
- `downloadTask2()` would return `Deferred<Int>` as Int is return type of function
- `downloadTask3()` would return `Deferred<Float>` as Float is return type of function

We can use the return object from `async` of type `Deferred<T>` to get the returned value in `T` type. That can be done with `await()` call. Check below code for example

```
        btnCount.setOnClickListener {
        pgBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            val currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val retVal1 = async(Dispatchers.IO) { downloadTask1() }
            val retVal2 = async(Dispatchers.IO) { downloadTask2() }
            val retVal3 = async(Dispatchers.IO) { downloadTask3() }

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "All tasks downloaded! ${retVal1.await()}, ${retVal2.await()}, ${retVal3.await()} in ${(System.currentTimeMillis() - currentMillis)/1000} seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pgBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }
```

This way, we've launched all 3 tasks concurrently. So, my total execution time to complete would be only `8 seconds` which is time for `downloadTask2()` as it is largest of all of 3 tasks. You can see this in following screenshot in `Toast message`

[image: await example]

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that `launch` is for **sequential** funs, while `async` for **concurrent**

Comment: You have used launch once for all the tasks and the async for each one. Maybe it's faster because each one was launched in another coroutine and doesn't wait someone? This is an incorrect comparison. Usually performance is the same. One key difference is that launch always start a new coroutine instead of async that splits the owner one. One more factor is that if one of async tasks would fail for a reason the parent coroutine will fail either. That's why async isn't as popular as launch.

Comment: This answer is not right, comparing async with suspend functions directly instead of launch. Instead of calling suspend function directly in example, if you call launch(Dispatchers.IO) {downloadTask1()} you will see that both are executed concurrently, not **sequentially**, you won't be able to get outputs but you will see that it's not sequential. Also if you do not concatenate deferred.await() and call deferred.await() separately you will see that async is sequential.

Comment: -1 this is just plain wrong. Both `launch` and `async` will start new coroutines. You're comparing a single coroutine with no children to a single coroutine with 3 children. You could replace each of the `async` invocations with `launch` and absolutely nothing would change with regard to concurrency.

Comment: The extraneous noise in this answer is adding complexity that is outside of the co-routine topic.

Comment: If you really want to compare it in this way you also need to `launch` all 3 download tasks in separate launch blocks. Otherwise you are mixing things up and confusing people. If you add `val job1 = launch(Dispatchers.IO) { downloadTask1() }`, `val job2 = ...` etc. Then you will really run it in parallel as you are suggesting with `async`.

Comment: this is wrong example. try `launch{downloadTask1()}` instead of `downloadTask1()` in launch test.

Comment: This answer completely misses the point and is plain wrong. It should be deleted.

Comment: not a fair comparison. do separate launch calls and you will get parallel executions as with async. this answer should be deleted.

Answer (score 9):

***launch*** returns a job

***async*** returns a result (deferred job)

`launch` with `join` is used to wait until the job gets finished. It simply suspends the coroutine calling `join()`, leaving the current thread free to do other work (like executing another coroutine) in the meantime.

`async` is used to compute some results. It creates a coroutine and returns its future result as an implementation of `Deferred`. The running coroutine is cancelled when the resulting deferred is cancelled.

Consider an async method that returns a string value. If the async method is used without `await` it will return a `Deferred` string but if `await` is used you will get a string as the result

---

The key difference between `async` and `launch`:
***Deferred returns a particular value of type T after your Coroutine finishes executing, whereas Job doesn’t.***

Answer (score 8):

Async and Launch, both are used to create coroutines that run in the background. In almost every situation one can use either of them.

tl;dr version:

When you dont care about the task's return value, and just want to run it, you may use Launch. If you need the return type from the task/coroutine you should use async.

**Alternate**:
However, I feel the above difference/approach is a consequence of thinking in terms of Java/one thread per request model. Coroutines are so inexpensive, that if you want to do something from the return value of some task/coroutine(lets say a service call) you are better off creating a new coroutine from that one. If you want a coroutine to wait for another coroutine to transfer some data, I would recommend using channels and not the return value from Deferred object. Using channels and creating as much number of coroutines as required, is the better way IMO

**Detailed answer**:

The only difference is in the return type and what functionality it provides.

Launch returns `Job` while Async returns `Deferred`. Interestingly enough, Deferred extends Job. Which implies it must be providing additional functionality on top of Job. Deferred is type parameterised over  where T is the return type. Thus, Deferred object can return some response from the block of code executed by async method.

p.s. I only wrote this answer because I saw some factually incorrect answers on this question and wanted to clarify the concept for everyone. Also, while working on a pet project myself I faced similar problem because of previous Java background.

Comment: "Async and Launch, both are used to create coroutines that run in the background" Coroutines doesn't necessarily mean `execute in background` unless you define it with `Dispatchers`. Your answer is making it even confusing for newbies

Answer (score 5):

[image]

**launch / async no result**

- Use when don't need the result,
- Don't block the code where is called,
- Run in sequential

**async for result**

- When you need to wait for the result and can run in parallel for
  efficiency,
- Block the code where is called,
- Run in concurrent

Answer (score 1):

Alongside the other great answers, for the people familiar with Rx and getting into coroutines, `async` returns a `Deferred` which is akin to `Single` while `launch` returns a `Job` that is more akin to `Completable`. You can `.await()` to block and get the value of the first one, and `.join()` to block until the `Job` is completed.