# When using kotlin coroutines, how do I unit test a function that calls a suspend function?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I have a class like this

```
class SomeClass {
    fun someFun() {
        // ... Some synchronous code
        async {
            suspendfun() 
        }
    }

    private suspend fun suspendFun() {
         dependency.otherFun().await()
         // ... other code
    }
}
```

I want to unit test `someFun()` so I wrote a unit test that looks like this:

```
@Test
fun testSomeFun() {
    runBlocking {
        someClass.someFun()
    }

    // ... verifies & asserts
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work because runBlocking doesn't actually block execution until everything inside runBlocking is done. If I test `suspendFun()` directly inside `runBlocking` it works as expected but I want to be able to test `someFun()` all together.

Any clue how to test a function with both sync and async code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Fixing async

As implemented, your `someFun()` will just “fire and forget” the `async` result. As a result, `runBlocking` does not make a difference in that test.

If possible, make `someFun()` return `async`'s `Deferred` and then, in `runBlocking`, call `await` on it.

```
fun someFun(): Deferred<Unit> {
    // ... Some synchronous code
    return async {
        suspendFun()
    }
}
```

Then the test:

```
runBlocking {
    SomeClass().someFun().await()
}
```

This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46226519/8073652) is a good resource for further information.

#### alternative: use launch

It's also possible to avoid `async` in favor of using `suspend` functions and a `launch`-created coroutine:

```
suspend fun someFun() {
    // ... Some synchronous code
    suspendFun()
}

private suspend fun suspendFun() {
    delay(1000)
    println("executed")
    // ... other code
}
```

The test uses `launch` and the outer `runBlocking` implicitly waits for its completion:

```
val myScope = GlobalScope
runBlocking {
    myScope.launch {
        SomeClass().someFun()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that if you don't call `.await()` an async block will not propogaate any exceptions?

Comment: You shouldn't use `async` if you ignore its return value. You should use `launch` instead so you get unhandled exceptions thrown in the resuming thread.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I see, I was misusing async when I should have been using launch.

Comment: Why `runBlocking { launch { ... }.join() }`? Can't you just use `runBlocking { ... }`?

Comment: @msrd0 you’re right, that has not always been the case though. I updated the code

Comment: Using the second approach, would we also need to cancel myScope in the teardown to avoid test bleed?