# kotlin coroutine - how to ensure some commands run on UI main thread when invoked inside coroutine?

Tags: kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope

i have a very simple coroutine that just does some delay and then what i want it to do is post commands to UI message queue. so run the last two lines on UI thread. here is the coroutine:

```
async{
    delay(5000)
    doSomething()
    doAnotherThing()
}
```

I want the last two methods doSomething() and doAnotherThing() to run on the UI thread ? how can this be done ? From what i have read the delay(5000) will automatically run asynchronously but how to make the rest run on UI thread ? To be very clear, i am doing this from an object that was launched from main thread.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`async` creates a coroutine and runs in the Coroutine context, inherited from a `CoroutineScope`, additional context elements can be specified with context argument. If the context does not have any dispatcher nor any other `ContinuationInterceptor`, then `Dispatchers.Default` is used.

If `Dispatchers.Default` is used then whatever function you invoke in `async` builder it will run asynchronously. To switch contexts you can use `withContext` function:

```
async {
    delay(5000)
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        // if we use `Dispatchers.Main` as a coroutine context next two lines will be executed on UI thread.
        doSomething()
        doAnotherThing()
    }
}
```

If `async` runs in the `Dispatchers.Main` context you don't need to switch contexts:

```
var job: Job = Job()
var scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)

scope.async {
    delay(5000) // suspends the coroutine without blocking UI thread

    // runs on UI thread
    doSomething() 
    doAnotherThing()
}
```

**Note**: `async` is mainly used for parallel executions. To start a simple coroutine `launch` builder is used. So you can replace all `async` functions in those examples on `launch` function.
Also to run coroutine with `async` builder you need to call `await()` function on `Deferred` object which is returned by `async` function. [Here is some additional info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46226518/what-is-the-difference-between-launch-join-and-async-await-in-kotlin-coroutines).

Comment: i could have also used  withContext(UI){//...} instead of the scope right ?  i dont find the package with CoroutineScope taking a parameter. maybe its in the latest kotlin which i dont have but thanks for hte insight on scopes.

Comment: Yes, to switch contexts you can use `withContext` function.