how to implement classic bluetooth timeout and error retry mechanism with coroutine
I want to implement classic bluetooth timeout and error retry mechanism with coroutine, i wrote below code. It gives me a timeout every ten seconds instead of every 5 seconds.
suspend fun connectClassicBluetoothDevice() {
    repeat(5) {
        try {
            withTimeout(5000) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    ensureActive()
                    println("${Date(System.currentTimeMillis())}: Coroutine is running $it")
                    suspendCancellableCoroutine<Boolean> { continuation ->
                        continuation.resume(blockCall())

                        continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
                            // call the BluetoothSocket.close() will immediately interrupt the blockCall()
                            // BluetoothSocket.close()
                            println("${Date(System.currentTimeMillis())}: Coroutine is cancelled")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {
            println("${Date(System.currentTimeMillis())}: timeout")
        }
    }
}

private fun blockCall() = try {
    // it is a block call that maybe takes 10 seconds to complete
    // BluetoothSocket.connect()
    true
} catch (e: Exception) {
    println("${Date(System.currentTimeMillis())}: exception")
    false
}

When i change it to below code, it works well for me, the timeout will be on time. I'm confused that why the timeout is not be on time in above code. So how to fix the above code's bug?
suspend fun connectClassicBluetoothDevice() {
    repeat(5) {
        try {
            withTimeout(5000) {
                ensureActive()
                println("${Date(System.currentTimeMillis())}: Coroutine is running $it")
                suspendCancellableCoroutine<Boolean> { continuation ->
                    thread {
                        continuation.resume(blockCall())
                    }

                    continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
                        // call the BluetoothSocket.close() will immediately interrupt the blockCall()
                        // BluetoothSocket.close()
                        println("${Date(System.currentTimeMillis())}: Coroutine is cancelled")
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {
            println("${Date(System.currentTimeMillis())}: timeout")
        }
    }
}

private fun blockCall() = try {
    // it is a block call that maybe takes 10 seconds to complete
    // BluetoothSocket.connect()
    true
} catch (e: Exception) {
    println("${Date(System.currentTimeMillis())}: exception")
    false
}


Hi, here is a small example from another post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191427/kotlin-coroutines-async-withtimeout-which-stops-blocking-the-thread-once-it-ru
