# How does exception propagation works on CoroutineScope.async?

Tags: kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I see multiple sources claiming that an exception happening inside an async{} block is not delivered anywhere and only stored in the `Deferred` instance. The claim is that the exception remains "hidden" and only influences things outside at the moment where one will call `await()`. This is often described as one of the main differences between `launch{}` and `async{}`. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46226519/7441319).

> An uncaught exception inside the async code is stored inside the
> resulting Deferred and is not delivered anywhere else, it will get
> silently dropped unless processed

According to this claim, at least the way I understand it, the following code should not throw, since no-one is calling await:

```
// throws
runBlocking {
  async { throw Exception("Oops") }
}
```

And yet, the exception gets thrown. This is also discussed [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2404#issuecomment-732298335), but I could not really understand **why** by reading this.

So it seems to me that when async throws, a "cancelation signal" is propagated on the parent scope, even if `await()` does not get called. Aka the exception does not really remain hidden, nor silently dropped, as the quote above states. Is my assumption correct?

Now, if we pass a `SupervisorJob()`, the code does **not** throw:

```
// does not throw
runBlocking {
  async(SupervisorJob()) { throw Exception("Oops") }
}
```

This seems reasonable since supervisor job is meant to swallow failures.

And now comes the part I do not understand at all. If we pass `Job()`, the code still runs without throwing, even though `Job()` is supposed to propagate failures to its parent scope:

```
// does not throw. Why?
runBlocking {
  async(Job()) { throw Exception("Oops") }
}
```

So my question is, why passing no Job throws, but passing either Job or SupervisorJob does not throw?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In some sense, the mess you experience is a consequence of Kotlin coroutines having been an early success, before they became stable. In their experimental days, one thing they lacked was structured concurrency, and a ton of web material got written about them in that state (such as your [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46226519/7441319) from 2017). Some of the then-valid preconceptions remained with people even after their maturation, and got perpetuated in even more recent posts.

The actual situation is quite clear — all you have to understand is coroutine hierarchy, which is mediated through the `Job` objects. It doesn't matter whether it's a `launch` or an `async`, or any further coroutine builder — they all behave uniformly.

With this in mind, let's go through your examples:

```
runBlocking {
  async { throw Exception("Oops") }
}
```

By writing just `async` you implicitly used `this.async`, where `this` is the `CoroutineScope` that `runBlocking` established. It contains the `Job` instance associated with the `runBlocking` coroutine. For this reason, the `async` coroutine becomes the child of `runBlocking`, so the latter throws an exception when the `async` coroutine fails.

```
runBlocking {
  async(SupervisorJob()) { throw Exception("Oops") }
}
```

Here you supply a standalone job instance which has no parent. This breaks the coroutine hierarchy and `runBlocking` does not fail. In fact, `runBlocking` doeesn't even wait for your coroutine to complete — add a `delay(1000)` to verify this.

```
runBlocking {
  async(Job()) { throw Exception("Oops") }
}
```

No new reasoning here — `Job` or `SupervisorJob`, it doesn't matter. You broke the coroutine hierarchy and the failure doesn't propagate.

Now let's explore a few more variations:

```
runBlocking {
    async(Job(coroutineContext[Job])) {
        delay(1000)
        throw Exception("Oops")
    }
}
```

Now we created a new `Job` instance, but we made it a child of `runBlocking`. This throws an exception.

```
runBlocking {
    async(Job(coroutineContext[Job])) {
        delay(1000)
        println("Coroutine done")
    }
}
```

Same as above, but now we don't throw an exception and the `async` coroutine completes normally. It prints `Coroutine done`, but then something unexpected happens: `runBlocking` does *not* complete, and the program hangs forever. Why?

This is maybe the trickiest part of this mechanism, but it still makes perfect sense once you think it through. When you create a coroutine, it internally creates its own `Job` instance — this happens always, whether or not you explicitly supply a job as an argument to `async`. If you supply an explicit job, it becomes the *parent* of that internally-created job.

Now, in the first case, where you didn't provide an explicit job, the parent job is the one internally created by `runBlocking`. It automatically completes when the `runBlocking` coroutine completes. But completion doesn't propagate to the parent the way cancellation does — you wouldn't want everything stopping just because one child coroutine completed normally.

So, when you create your own `Job` instance and supply it as the parent of the `async` coroutine, that job of yours isn't getting completed by anything. If the coroutine fails, the failure propagates to your job, but if it completes normally, your job eternally stays in the original state of "in progress".

And finally, let's bring in `SupervisorJob` again:

```
runBlocking {
    async(SupervisorJob(coroutineContext[Job])) {
        delay(1000)
        throw Exception("Oops")
    }
}
```

This just runs forever without any output, because `SupervisorJob` swallows the exception.