# Why do we need "GlobalScope.launch{}" when we already have "GlobalScope.async{}" that does the same and more in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

doesn't `Global.async{}` do the same things that `Global.launch{}` does and more?
If yes, then why did they invent `Global.launch{}`?
please provide a solid situation if possible.

I already searched a lot, but didn't find a convincing answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between launch/join and async/await in Kotlin coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46226518/what-is-the-difference-between-launch-join-and-async-await-in-kotlin-coroutines)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address the obvious difference: `async` coroutines can return a value, whereas `launch` coroutines can't. I guess you know this, and are asking if `launch` does anything that can't be done with an `async` coroutine that returns `Unit`.

The primary difference between `async` and `launch` is the way they handle errors when launched as root coroutines. A root coroutine is a coroutine that is launched directly in a root scope, rather than as a child of an existing coroutine.

When you create a root coroutine with `launch`, exceptions are propagated to the scope's `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, if it has one. This is because the error would otherwise be lost. The job doesn't return a result, so there's nowhere else in the code that would be able to handle the error.

However, when you create a root coroutine with `async`, exceptions are caught and contained in the resulting `Deferred` object. The exception is thrown when you call `await`. It doesn't propagate to the `UncaughtExceptionHandler`. This is because we expect that some other code will eventually `await` the result of the job and handle the error.

This distinction only applies to root coroutines. When you start a coroutine as a child of an existing coroutine, errors are always propagated to the parent job, regardless of whether the coroutine was started with `async` or `launch`.

So, to answer your question, `launch` provides the additional capability to handle errors with an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` when launching root coroutines.

Comment: Thanks Sam, you clarified it more for me. I read the answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46226518/what-is-the-difference-between-launch-join-and-async-await-in-kotlin-coroutines as Alex.T and Jeff Bowman
pointed out and I found it very useful but you clarified it more. Thanks.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Roman's answer to the linked question is out-of-date, thanks to the introduction (by him, ironically) of structured concurrency. In his answer he says that an uncaught exception inside an `async` coroutine is always dropped unless you `await` it. In fact, that's no longer true for coroutines launched as a child of an existing coroutine. In that case, a failed `async` job will still cause its parent job to fail. Roman's original answer is still true for root coroutines, though.